# Replace every cell in a matrix with the average of adjcent cells

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Requirement: Must be done in-place.

For example:

Given matrix

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Should replace by the average of its  sum of 3*3 neighbor cells and its own:

```
(1+2+4+5)/4,       (2+1+3+4+5+6)/6 ,            (3+2+6+5)/4
(1+2+5+4+7+8)/6,   (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)/9,       (2+3+5+6+8+9)/6
(4+5+7+8)/4,       (4+5+6+7+8+9)/6,             (5+6+8+9)/4
```

which is:

```
All floating number convert to int

3,      3.5(3), 4             3, 3, 4
4.5(4),  5, 5.5(5)  =>        4, 5, 5
6,      6.5(6), 7             6, 6, 7
```

I tried to just iterate over the matrix and update each cell, but I found this will affect the future calculation:

Say I update the original 1 to 3, but when I when I tried to update the original 2, the original 1 becomes 3 now.

Copying the original matrix for calculating average is a workaround but it's a bad idea, Could we achieve that without using that much space?

Comment: Creating a copy of the matrix before updating the cells is the usual approach. If the matrix is very, very big, you could just hold a "rolling" backup, e.g. the previous and current line, or even less.

Comment: Say you have a 1000x1000 matrix and you are updating the cells row by row. When in row n, you don't need a copy of row n-2 (because it's not relevant any more), and neither of row n+1 (because it has still the original values. So keeping a backup of just the previous and current row would be enough. Whether it's worth the effort is another question.

Comment: @tobias_k Could you please explain the details of "rolling" backup in detail? I think this might be the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, you should just create a copy of the original matrix and use that for calculating the averages. Unless creating a copy of the matrix would use more memory than you have available, the overhead should be negligible.

If you have a *really* large matrix, you could use a "rolling" backup (in lack of a better term). Let's say you update the cells row-by-row and you are currently in row *n*. You don't need a backup of row *n-2*, as those cells are not relevant any more, and neither of row *n+1*, because those are still the original values. So you can just keep a backup of the previous and the current row. Whenever you advance to the next row, discard the backup of the previous row, move the backup of the current row to previous, and create a backup of the new current row.

Some pseudo-code (not taking any edge-cases into account):

```
previous = []  # or whatever works for the first row
for i in len(matrix):
    current = copy(matrix[i])
    for k in len(matrix[i]):
         matrix[i][k] = previous[k-1] + ... + current[k] + ... matrix[i+1][k+1] / 9
    previous = current
```

(You might also keep a backup of the *next* row, just so you can use only the backup rows for all the values instead of having to differentiate.)

Answer (score 0):

You must have some kind of cache for the result data so you can keep reference to the original data. I don't think there is a way around it.

If the data set is large, you could optimize by using a smaller data buffer (like looking through a keyhole) and 'scrolling' the input matrix as you update it. In your case, you could use a buffer as small as 3x3.
It is a compromise between speed and space though. The smaller your buffer, the worse the performance will be.

To visualize the problem, starting from the top-left (0,0) of the dataset:
*(result values are rounded down for simplicity)*

First step: update first 4 cells (prime the buffer)

```
// Data Set        // Data Viewport // Result Set
01,02,03,04,05     01,02,03         04,04,??
06,07,08,09,10     06,07,08         06,07,??
11,12,13,14,15     11,12,13         ??,??,??
16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25
```

**then for each iteration..**
*( new values indicated with [xx] )*

++ update first column in Data Set from Result Set

```
// Data Set        // Data Viewport   // Result Set
[04],02,03,04,05   01,02,03         04,04,??
[06],07,08,09,10   06,07,08         06,07,??
 11 ,12,13,14,15   11,12,13         ??,??,??
 16 ,17,18,19,20
 21 ,22,23,24,25
```

++ shift Data Viewport and Result Set right 1 column

```
// Data Set        // Data Viewport // Result Set
[04],02,03,04,05   02,03,04         04,[03],??
[06],07,08,09,10   07,08,09         07,[08],??
 11 ,12,13,14,15   12,13,14         ??, ?? ,??
 16 ,17,18,19,20
 21 ,22,23,24,25
```

++ update middle column of Result Set

```
// Data Set        // Data Viewport // Result Set
[04],02,03,04,05   02,03,04         04,[05],??
[06],07,08,09,10   07,08,09         07,[08],??
 11 ,12,13,14,15   12,13,14         ??, ?? ,??
 16 ,17,18,19,20
 21 ,22,23,24,25
```

**At the following iteration, the data state would be:**

```
// Data Set        // Data Viewport // Result Set
04,[04],03,04,05   03,04,05         05,[06],??
06,[07],08,09,10   08,09,10         08,[09],??
11, 12 ,13,14,15   13,14,15         ??, ?? ,??
16, 17 ,18,19,20
21, 22 ,23,24,25
```

.. etc

Don't forget to handle the other edge cases.

**The Data Viewport representation is just for visualization. In code, the actual viewport would be the result buffer.*

Comment: Could you explain this further? I don't really get how a cache of 3x3 cells can be enough...

Comment: I made a mistake in the 2nd step. The values in the Data viewport should match the Data Set. Updated. In the example, I'm updating only the 2 cells in the middle column of the result set for (main) iteration. You could make the buffer any size, as long as it's at least 3x3.  This is a technique for navigating infinite data spaces (you can't cache any row or column because they are boundless. Doing it this way, you are limited only by index size. In rendering, this is called a clip-space algorithm, as I know it. That help?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right - we use a 3*3 buffer, and update the all elements won't involved with the other element's average. I think this is the ideal way, but it's hard to implement into code.

Comment: Yes, that's right.. If you were using a 3(rows) x 5(columns) buufer in my example, not including edge cases, you would be able to update the entire first and 2nd rows of the buffer.

Comment: I totally believe you, but I still don't get it. Maybe you could add some pseudo code or a link to the algorithm to better explain the order in which the cells are updated.

Comment: I've elaborated my example a bit to show the state at the intermediate steps and the following step.  Hopefully that makes it easier to understand what's happening. This is basically the same things as you have described, except in 2D, whereas your method would be 1D (row by row). I normally use this method in 3D. Just extrapolate what you are doing in your own method. Use a rectangle instead of a line.